# Saving a tkinter output to an sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, sqlite, tkinter-entry

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm trying to save the input from a tkinter entry box to a field in a sqlite database. However, however I try to do so, it always saves as a variation of PY_VAR(number) or simply prints as {}. This is the relevant section of code (the SQL queries are all valid in context of my database). How would I go about rectifying this so an entry input would save to the relevant column in the SQL database? 
`

```
    enteredName = StringVar()
    nameEntry = Entry(mainFrame,textvariable = enteredName)
    nameEntry.grid(row = 3 + recordNo,column=4)
    c.execute("SELECT name FROM purchases WHERE productID = (?)", 
    (recordNo,))
    savedName = c.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    if savedName != "":
        nameEntry.insert(1,savedName)
    nameToSave=str(enteredName.get())
    c.execute("UPDATE purchases SET name = ? WHERE productID = ?", 
    (nameToSave,recordNo))
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.get()` to `.get("1.0", "end-1c")`. The `1.0` makes it be read from the first character and `end-1c` makes it read till the end of the text box. The `1c` part removes the extra newline the text box will add.